# How to set bash auto logout expiration in ubuntu 20.04

Tags: linux, ubuntu, bash

How to set bash auto logout expiration in ubuntu 20.04 ?

I,m setting the variable **TMOUT** for **root** user to **2 hours** on my **server** using following **bash**-command:

```
sudo export TMOUT=7200
```

But it does not work at all, are there any other solutions to achieve this, other than putting that variable in my `.profile` ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could set a log out script in `/etc/profile.d`:

- Create the file `/etc/profile.d/autologout.sh`:

  `sudo nano /etc/profile.d/autologout.sh`
- The contents of `autologout.sh`:

  ```bsh
  #!/bin/sh
  # Sets auto log out for all users to 2 hours
  TMOUT=7200
  readonly TMOUT
  export TMOUT
  ```
- Set permissions for the script:

  `sudo chmod 0755 /etc/profile.d/autologout.sh`
- Reload the profile or log out and back in.

  `source /etc/profile.d/autologout.sh`

Comment: looking good so far, i changed your first command as following: `$ nano /etc/profile.d/autologout.sh`, since i could not `cat` something that did not exist. Also you forgot to mention that i have to log out once it completed and log in again, so it will take effect then. Please could you update your answer accordently ? This will be good to know :).

Comment: You should also reload profile using following command: `$ source /etc/profile.d/autologout.sh`, without running that command you will still get auto logout

Comment: To finish, i had also to rename the file `autologout.sh` to `autologout`, since it will be executed by `run-parts`.

Comment: I don't believe you need to rename `autologout.sh` to `autologout,`, there are other `.sh` files  in `/etc/profile.d` but I made the other changes you suggested.

Comment: As @JoshZhang introduced, i had to do followings:

 1. Create the file in folder **/etc/profile.d** and make sure the file is `run-parts`-conform

    `nano /etc/profile.d/autologout`

 2. Then add the commands

    `TMOUT=7200`

    `readonly TMOUT`

    `export TMOUT`

 3. Then i tested that program `run-parts` will execute my script properly

    `run-parts --test /etc/profile.d`

 4. I verify then my setting (TMOUT-variable)

    `echo $TMOUT`

 5. I then reload or update profiles without a reboot

    `source /etc/profile.d/autologout`